# opencv python smudge image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to create a program that smudges a selected part of an image. For example, in the case of image below.

[image]

I want to smudge all the pixels inside the parabola (between it and the line).

The program should stretch one side and squeeze the other side, within the selected range.

I'm storing all of the pixels found between the median line and the parabola in an np.array of type np.int32.

I'm thinking about using the cv.remap function, but unsure how to do so.

Comment: why a parabola? what have you tryied?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.